# WPF – Insert Resource Dictionary in C# into XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

By this way I can access **XAML resources** in **C# code**:

```
var resource = new ResourceDictionary
{
    Source = new Uri("/myAssemblyName;component/Themes/MyStyle.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)
};
```

---

I thinking about a reverse approach. I would like define **resource dictionary** in **C# code** like this:

```
public class MyColors : ResourceDictionary
{
    public MyColors ()
    {
        this.Add("MyGreen", Color.FromRgb(10, 211, 12)); // this["MyGreen"] = Color.FromRgb(10, 211, 12);
    }
}
```

And then include this **resource dictionary** into **XAML style file** like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="MyColors.cs" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyGreenBrush" Color="{StaticResource MyGreen}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

---

The question is about **possibility of including resource dictionary into XAML file**. Because presented approach not working – error: *Unexpected project file type at …\MyColors.cs*.

Comment: if you call the TryFindResource you are instructing the all to look in the resources for the key value

Comment: @MikeT By `TryFindResource` I can find resource from XAML, right? I would like use a reverse approach. In XAML file, look for resource from C# code file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to construct your created class inside `MergedDictionaries`

```
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <yourClassXmlNamespace:MyColors/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyGreenBrush" Color="{StaticResource MyGreen}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should build the dictionary in XAML

this will look as follows

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_ScratchPad">
    <Color x:Key="MyGreen">#0ad30c</Color>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

then as your are correctly doing you merge the controls dictionary

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="MyColors.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

If you really need to create your dictionary in code then you would merge it as follows

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <yourxmlns:MyColors/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

once you have added the dictionary to the control you don'[t need to instantiate a separate instance of the dictionary to access it instead just call TryFindResource as this keeps the override structure intact